# ruby injecting methods as parameters

Tags: ruby

So am trying to write functional ruby and for this purpose need to inject lambdas where ever required. But this is turning out to be not so elegant and useful. Example:

```
def this_is_a_test(arg1, fn_one = self.default_fn_one, fn_two = self.default_fn_two)
  #Something here
end
```

There are two disadvantages about this:

1. If I need to inject more methods, the arity becomes too big
2. If I want to only inject `fn_two` and use default for `fn_one` its not possible

So I tried this approach (picked up the idea from rails):

```
def this_is_a_test(arg1, options = {})
  opts = {
    fn_one: self.default_fn_one,
    fn_two: self.default_fn_two
  }.merge(options)

#Something here

end
```

This does take care of those two cases but I wanted to know if this is the best approach? Is there a way to do this without the options hash?

Comment: Looks like you want to bundle stuff in an object?

Comment: If there was only one function as parameter, you could use a block parameter, but since multiple are needed it can't be helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `method` and explicit `proc` or `lambda` constructs. In Ruby 2.0, your opts hash can also be removed entirely by using named parameters. (Amend your opts hash approach if you want to target earlier versions of Ruby too.)

```
def this_is_a_test(arg1,
                   fn_one: method(:default_fn_one),
                   fn_two: method(:default_fn_two))
  puts fn_one.call
  puts fn_two.call
  yield if block_given? # allow to pass an optional block too
end

this_is_a_test(:foo, fn_one: lambda { :bar } do
  puts :baz
end
```

(untested, but should put you in the right direction.)

Comment: Additionally, you can use *args in the this_is_a_test method definition and do `args.each{|arg| puts arg.call}`

Comment: I am not using 2.0 yet but wouldn't this again have the same problem as what I had mentioned?

Comment: If the args are named (Ruby 2.0) or passed in a hash, the arity problem goes away.